# References with explanations of how works CORDIC algorithm for division

Tags: reference, cordic, how-does-it-work

Does anyone know any available reference to learn how works CORDIC algorithm to implement a division?

Comment: I suppose you have already read the Wikipedia article? https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cordic

Comment: offcourse, but that article use trigonometric function to explain how it works.

Comment: This is more of a Stack Overflow kind of question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an excellent article written by someone on the Parallax forums, called CORDIC For Dummies. Well written and explains things nicely: https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/127241/cordic-for-dummies

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

A ***CORDIC division*** is implemented using ***CORDIC multiplication***, rearranging as follows: <sup>[[source]](http://www.drdobbs.com/184404244)</sup>

```
c = a/b
a - c*b = 0
```

For the multiplication `z = x*y`:

> ***z*** is composed of shifted versions of ***y***. The unknown value for ***z***, may be found by driving ***x*** to zero 1 bit at a time. If the *i <sup>th</sup>* bit of ***x*** is nonzero, ***y** <sup>i</sup>* is right shifted by *i* bits and added to the current value of ***z***. The *i <sup>th</sup>* bit is then removed from ***x*** by subtracting *2<sup>-i</sup>* from ***x***. If ***x*** is negative, the *i <sup>th</sup>* bit in the twos complement format would be removed by adding *2<sup>-i</sup>*. In either case, when ***x*** has been driven to zero all bits have been examined and ***z*** contains the signed product of ***x*** and ***y*** correct to *B* bits.
>
> This algorithm is similar to the standard shift and add multiplication algorithm except for two important features:
>
> 1. Arithmetic right shifts  are used instead of left shifts, allowing signed numbers to be used.
> 2. Computing the product to *B* bits with the CORDIC algorithm is equivalent to rounding the result of the standard algorithm to the most significant *B* bits.

The division `z = x/y` is found...

> ... by driving ***x*** to zero using right-shifted versions of ***y***. If the current residual is positive, the *i <sup>th</sup>* bit in ***z*** is set. Likewise, if the residual is negative the ith bit in ***z*** is cleared.
>
> ```
> divide_4q(x,y){
>    for (i=1; i=<B; i++){
>       if (x > 0)
>         if (y > 0)
>            x = x - y*2^(-i);
>            z = z + 2^(-i);
>         else
>            x = x + y*2^(-i);
>            z = z - 2^(-i);
>       else          
>          if (y > 0)
>             x = x + y*2^(-i);
>             z = z - 2^(-i);
>          else
>             x = x - y*2^(-i);
>             z = z + 2^(-i);
>    }
>    return(z)
> }
> ```

You'll have to make a few modifications to use floating point numbers.

Comment: Since the Dr Dobb's website doesn't have all the detail, you can read the PDF at: http://www.siue.edu/~gengel/pdf/cordic.pdf

Comment: NOTE: if the bit about driving a X to zero (in Z = X*Y) sounded confusing: you are adding a multiple of Y to Z, for each set bit in X. Keep adding to the running total, until you run out of bits in X.